# Error when Display Images on Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, imageview, android-volley, networkimageview

**SOLVED**

im try to display images on dialog box.
when im click item from listview so dialog will show with details items from when im click.
but when im try display images i got error and here the log says :

com.felix.tirtagympool.AbdominalFragment.onItemClick(AbdominalFragment.java:164 = thumbnail.setImageUrl(exerciseList.get(position).getGambar1(), imageLoader)

```
    05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.felix.tirtagympool, PID: 13073
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.felix.tirtagympool.AbdominalFragment.onItemClick(AbdominalFragment.java:164)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-11 21:57:19.958 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 21:57:21.298 13073-13073/com.felix.tirtagympool I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13073 SIG: 9
```

here my abdominalfragment.java
**Change This code**

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
NetworkImageView thumbnail = (NetworkImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gambar11);
// thumbnail image
thumbnail.setImageUrl(exerciseList.get(position).getGambar1(), imageLoader);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Like This**

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
NetworkImageView thumbnail1 = (NetworkImageView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gambar11);
thumbnail1.setImageUrl(exerciseList.get(position).getGambar1(), imageLoader);
```